# PayPal Accounts creation: No redirection to PayPal

Tags: django, paypal, account-management, django-paypal

I am developing a Django-based website in which each new user creates a wallet to hold his money. I'd like to integrate it with PayPal, so that when the user signs up, a PayPal account is automatically created for him with the credit card information he entered.

From my research, the way to go seems to be using the PayPal Adaptative Accounts API. However, from what I've read in this document (https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_AdaptiveAccounts.pdf), it seems the user has to be redirected to the PayPal website once the account is created in order to provide some information and/or confirm the account.

- Is it possible to make it transparent to the user, i.e. make it so he
  is not redirected to the PayPal website?
- Is the Adaptative Accounts API appropriate or is there another
  solution I should look into?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've not used it myself, but I've heard that the Django-Paypal application is really good: https://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal

Comment: Thanks Gareth. I audited it and it is indeed an excellent Django application that works with the Direct Payment option from PayPal. However, it only allows you to process payments, not create PayPal accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the whole point behind PayPal and Google Checkout is that they're both trusted sources with their own, well-known SSL solutions, so customers who check out through them know exactly what they're getting.  You'll get a callback (or you can poll for transactions) from the checkout provider letting you know how the transaction with the customer went.

If you want a solution that allows you to use your own website for everything, use a merchant solution provider like Authorize.Net.  You'll have to acquire a valid enterprise-level SSL certificate and demonstrate that you're fully in compliance with all regulations regarding handling customer information.  Have fun with that.

Comment: Thank you Elf.

For Merchant solutions like Authorize.net users: is it painful to setup? Do you advise to rather go with the PayPal way of creating new accounts?

Comment: "It depends."  Mostly on how big you are.  A small-time business can get by with Paypal and Google Checkout, and you don't need anything but a bank account, a credit card with a record, and maybe your social security number.  (You'll be limited without that, as Google has to abide by  certain tax laws and regulations.)  For bigger companies, Authorize lets you maintain the consistent transaction you asked for in your original post, and costs less per transaction, so you keep more cash.  But it's hard to set up, and has much stricter regulations.